# Magento 2: Page Title not working for wishlist_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, wishlist, navigation

*here am trying to add page title for wish list in sidebar navigation, but page title is not showing up. here is my
wishlist_index_index.xml overrided file.*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Wishlist</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
                <action method="addCrumb">
                    <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                    <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                        <item name="link" xsi:type="string">../../../</item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addCrumb">
                    <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Wishlist</argument>
                    <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Wishlist</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Wishlist</item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="wishlist_head_components" template="Magento_Wishlist::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="view.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
                                <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.inner" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-details</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons" label="Wishlist Control Buttons">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="button/update.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="button/share.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="button/tocart.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

*Where am doing wrong?. can I get help? Thank you*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the same code in the layout my wishlist_index_index.xml and nothing has changed !

I think the problem is from same css class.. Try to remove the arguments '**css_class**' !

What is your magento version ?

[image]

Comment: thank you aissyass for your responce, ill check for css part

Comment: hi aissayass, am using 2.3.1 Enterprise Edition , i removed Css links, but page title still in not showing.

Comment: thank you aissyass you are correct. I fixed it by CSS changes.

Comment: Your welcome :)